# Using CSS for navigation bar in Wordpress Theme

Tags: html, css, wordpress, html-lists, styling

I have a custom WordPress theme and my navigation bar is implemented fine however I have this bit of CSS (style.css):

```
#navbar li a.active{

background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
border-top: 3px solid; 
border-color:#d22b2b;
}
```

This is the styling for the button that the current page is on, so it shows which page is currently active, this is a bit tricky to implement with WordPress as the HTML (index.php) is like this:

```
<div id="navbar">
<div class="navbarcontainer">

          <ul align="center">
          <?php wp_list_pages('title_li=');?>

          </ul>

</div>
</div>
```

Now I can't add `class="active"` because I can't see the list items in the unordered list.
Need a way I can add `class="active"` to each page.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough rep to comment but just curious why not use native WordPress menus? It'll make your life easier going down the road as well if you use wp_nav_menu();

See here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

Properly using a menu that way will automatically apply this class to the active menu item:

```
.current-menu-item
```

That's just native functionality. Let me know if you decide to go that way and I'll be happy to help.

In your functions.php file add:

```
register_nav_menus('menu_slug' => 'Menu Name');
```

This will allow you to assign a menu in the backend. Go to Appearance -> Menus.

Then where you're trying to call the menu, add this code:

```
wp_nav_menu('menu'=> 'menu_slug');
```

That will then pull the menu you created in the backend. There are lots of arguments you can pass to that wp_nav_menu function as well.

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => '',
    'menu_class'      => 'menu',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
```

);

If you use it this way, add this code to your theme and then:

```
    wp_nav_menu ( $defaults );
```

You'll notice if you do it that way, WordPress will automatically give the active menu item a current class. I hope this helps. This honestly is the best (right) way to do it. At some point you might want to switch the arrangement of menu items or add sub-menus or have a page you don't want to show. Using the menus like this will help you substantially.

Comment: I am using my own theme and I want the webpage looking exactly as I want... unfortunately I can't have that with the native WordPress themes

Comment: Ryman, I updated my answer to try and explain this a little better. You can use wp_nav_menu with your custom theme. Hope this helps!